# More efficient to merge data-frames or merge dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

I need to iterate over many JSON files, extract the (certain) data I need, and conclude with one large data-frame representing data from all of the files. My question is, should I collect the data from each file as a dictionary and continue to update that dictionary with subsequent files, or turn each file dictionary into a data-frame and concatenate them one at a time? Or is there an even better and more efficient way? Thank you.

Edit: The data is nested and I have do some processing/cleaning to it. So far, I've been iterating over files, reading data into a dictionary, using pd.json_normalize to un-nest data, apply(pd.Series) to expand list value data, save as one data-frame per file, then concatenating data-frames from each file.

Comment: What does the data look like? Ik makes quite a difference if the json is nested or not. Also: what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is nested and I have do some processing/cleaning to it. So far, I've been iterating over files, reading data into a dictionary, using pd.json_normalize to un-nest data, apply(pd.Series) to expand list value data, save as one data-frame per file, then concatenating data-frames from each file.

Comment: In that case you really need to specify this question, add sample data and code and indicate where in the process you're stuck.

Comment: Can you include your code that you used so far and an example of your JSON files? This is difficult to answer without measuring an implementation. You only get opinion based responses like the one from @DhyanilMehta without source or reproducibility whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not stuck, I was just curious if it would be optimal to concatenate the data-frames from each file, or turn those into dictionaries and update one large dictionary, then turn that to a data-frame at the end of processing.

Answer (score 1):

Updating dictionary will be more efficient than concatenating dataframes as dataframes carry an overhead of managing indices and all with them while dictionaries are implemented as a hash table.